# Convert JSON/CSS-like Formated String to XML in PHP

Tags: php, xml, string

Is possible to convert formatted string to xml format or array in PHP? I have string format like this:

```
$prop = "
    large {
       width: 10px;
       height: 10px;
    }
    small {
       width: 5px;
       height: 5px;
    }
";
```

I want this string converted to xml format or array like:

```
<large>
    <width>10px</width>
    <height>10px</height>
</large>
<small>
    <width>5px</width>
    <height>5px</height>
</small>

$array = array(
    "large" => array(
        "width" => "10px",
        "height" => "10px"
    ),
    "small" => array(
        "width" => "5px",
        "height" => "5px"
    )
);
```

Thanks.

Comment: What does the format qualify? And actually array does not work if this is CSS as there can be duplicate keys.

Comment: This is not for CSS. I will use them for my app property like config etc. The keys above is only sample. To read the property i'm using `read('config.debugger.debug_mode');`. I do this to simplify the property assignment and simplify property reading. Also the `read()` function will works anywhere, so I doesn't need to use $GLOBALS['config']; Thanks.

Comment: Good to know, did look like CSS in the first place. It's also a good idea when you ask the question to add such context. E.g. you could use something that exists first, like a properties file or yaml. or even just an array. As for your solution: Please move it from the question into an answer. That is the proper way, the solution does not belong in the question.

Comment: @harke: Thanks for your guide. I'm new in here and my english is not good. :(

Comment: Why don't you use JSON with [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/de/function.json-decode.php) ?

Answer (score 4):

Because your input data is nicely formatted you can create a very simple recursive descendant parser - even not that much recursion involved. Or just with a simple stack:

```
$props = array_filter(array_map('trim', explode("\n", $prop)));
$stack = [$node = $xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<root/>')];

foreach ($props as $str)
{
    if ($str === '}') {
        array_pop($stack);
        $node = end($stack);
        continue;
    }

    if (preg_match('~^(\w+) {$~', $str, $matches)) {
        $node = $stack[] = $node->addChild($matches[1]);
        continue;
    }

    if (preg_match('~^(\w+):\s*(.*)$~', $str, $matches)) {
        $node->addChild($matches[1], htmlspecialchars($matches[2]));
        continue;
    }

    throw new UnexpectedValueException(sprintf('Unable to parse: "%s"', $str));
}

$xml->asXML('php://output');
```

The output for your second example (previously missing) then is (beautified):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <button>
    <large>
      <bond>
        <width>10px;</width>
        <height>10px;</height>
      </bond>
      <style>
        <background>
          <color>#ffffff;</color>
          <image>url(www.px.com/aui.png) -10px;</image>
          <another>
            <width>100px;</width>
            <height>100px;</height>
          </another>
        </background>
      </style>
    </large>
    <small>
      <bond>
        <width>10px;</width>
        <height>10px;</height>
      </bond>
      <style>
        <color>#fff;</color>
        <border>1px solid #000;</border>
      </style>
    </small>
  </button>
</root>
```

I recommend you use XML here because it can represent the structure better than an array which can not have duplicate keys.

It would be also possible to use recursive function calls instead of the stack. But this requires to wrap the input stream in a no-rewind iterator to not break (or using `array_shift` but I do not like that much):

```
$parse = function($p, SimpleXMLElement $t) use (&$parse) {
    foreach($p as $s) {
        if ($s === '}') {
            break;
        }

        if (preg_match('~^([^ ]+) {$~', $s, $m)) {
            $p->next();
            $parse($p, $t->addChild($m[1]));
            continue;
        }

        if (preg_match('~^([^:]+):\s*(.*)$~', $s, $m)) {
            $n = $t->addChild($m[1], htmlspecialchars($m[2]));
            continue;
        }
    }
};

$props = array_filter(array_map('trim', explode("\n", $prop)));
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<root/>');
$parse(new NoRewindIterator(new ArrayIterator($props)), $xml);

$xml->asXML('php://output');
```

Answer (score 1):

solution that does work :-)

```
$prop = "
    large {
       width: 10px;
       height: 10px;
       color: red;
    }
    small {
       width: 5px;
       height: 5px;
    }
    medium {
       width: 5px;
       height: 5px;
    }
";

//remove carriage return
 $prop = str_replace(array('.', ' ', "\n", "\t", "\r"), '', $prop);

 //get into main names and values
 preg_match_all('/([^\{]+)\{([^\}]+)\}/i',$prop,$matches);

 $arr_names = $matches[1];
 $arr_values = $matches[2];

 $arr_result = array();
 foreach($arr_names as $i=>$name){
     $value = $arr_values[$i];

     //get into main sub names and values
     preg_match_all('/([^\:]+)\:([^\;]+)\;/i',$value,$m);
     $arr_n = $m[1];
     $arr_v = $m[2];

     $arr = array();
     foreach($arr_n as $j=>$n){
        $v = $arr_v[$j];   
        $arr[$n] = $v;
     }

     $arr_result[$name] = $arr;
 }

 print_r($arr_result);
```

Comment: Yes it's works with 2 dimension format, but wont work with 3 or more dimension. I have try to create new format with `button->large->bound->width` and fail. But I have found my solution with `preg_replace` and `eval()` and works well with multi dimension format. Thank you.

Comment: Well - too bad you didn't write it in your question !

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
$elements = explode('}', trim($prop));
for($i = 0 ; $i < sizeof($elements); $i++) {
    list($name, $styles) = explode('{', $elements[$i]);
    $name = trim($name);
    if(empty($name)) {
        continue;
    }
    $rules = explode(';', $styles);
    for($j=0; $j < sizeof($rules); $j++) {
        list($ruleName, $ruleVal) = explode(':', $rules[$j]);
        $ruleName = trim($ruleName);
        if(empty($ruleName)) {
            continue;
        }
        $result[$name][$ruleName] = trim($ruleVal);
    }
}   
echo '<pre>';
var_dump($result);
echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: Thanks @Freeman Latif, but it's doesn't work. I try to build multi dimensional array with formated string but it fail.

Comment: I just tried it and it worked. Can you tell me the error messages that you get?

Comment: Yes it's work with `$prop` in sample above. But I try to create new format with 3 dimension format and the code wont work.

Answer (score -1):

**My Solution:**

I try to using `preg_replace()` and `eval()` and worked with multi dimension format. Maybe you can improve my `preg_replace` pattern.

```
$string = "
    button {
        large {
            bond {
                width: 10px;
                height: 10px;
            }
            style {
                background {
                    color: #ffffff;
                    image: url(www.px.com/aui.png) -10px;
                    another {
                        width: 100px;
                        height: 100px;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        small {
            bond {
                width: 10px;
                height: 10px;
            }
            style {
                color: #fff;
                border: 1px solid #000;
            }
        }
    }
";

$string = preg_replace("/(\s+\:)/", ':', $string);
$string = preg_replace("/(\:\s+)/", ':', $string);
$string = preg_replace("/(\s+\{)/", '{', $string);

$string = preg_replace("/([\w\d_]+)\:(.*?)\;/", '"$1" => "$2",', $string);
$string = preg_replace("/([\w\d_]+)\{/", '"$1" => array (', $string);
$string = preg_replace("/\}/", ')', $string);

$string = preg_replace("/\"\,(\s+)\)/", '"$1)', $string);
$string = preg_replace("/\)(\s+)\"/", '),$1"', $string);

$arr = eval('return array('.$string.');');
print_r($arr);
```

Thanks.

Comment: eval isn't a good choice (here), it could end your script in case of an error and it's dangerous (http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php).

Comment: @pce: Thanks. I don't know it before. I've try to use `$arr = array($string)` but it's indexed with `$arr[0] => array`. :(

Comment: `$arr = array($string)[0]` is not working in PHP 5.4 and older. Also  when using `$arr = array($string)[0]` the ouput is string, not array.

Comment: Yes, I've use it before and the output is string. The output should `array( [button] => array(` not `"button" => array (`.

Comment: ok,i thought your problem is *it's indexed with $arr[0]*.